# Comparing and displaying SQL results efficiently

Tags: php, sql

I've got a friend with a forum of whom I'm helping out. Said forum also has a shoutbox which stores data of userids (integers) who have been banned, UNIX of when they were banned, and who they've been banned by (userid/integer) in a SQL table. That data is in the `shoutbox` table. I'm trying to make a page where the forum moderators can go to see the users who are banned, who they were banned by, and when they were banned. 
Let's say that the table `users` is the table which has a column of data called `chat_banned` which stores a variable depending on if the user is banned or not where `1` is for banned and `0` for not banned. This data is in two different tables where `shoutbox` contains info on when the user was banned, and integers of the user's id who was banned and who did the banning and `users` says if they are actually banned or not.
The reason I cannot simply print the results of just the `shoutbox` table is because the user could have been unbanned and the only way to check he or she wasn't unbanned is to check the variable in the `chat_banned` column of the `users` table.
Is there any super efficient way to do the following:

- Build an array of some sort of all the banned users (my current data being selected is `userid` and `username` from `users` for convenience).
- List the array with the user who banned him/her and when he or she was banned
- Sort this list by UNIX time from recent to oldest.

I've already got a basic page setup so if you would like to see sample base function of it, I'll gladly post it here to see if there's any way to simply edit the page I've got built up to finish this efficiently.
Thanks, Dizzy.
**Edit:** I figured I'd list out a little more efficiently of what table has what information and what it is. Here you go:

- `users`

  - `chat_banned` (1 for banned, 0 for not banned)
- `shoutbox`

  - `time` (UNIX time stamp of when the command was executed)
  - `command` (command log of three possible commands, `ban` for banning a user, `unban` for unbanning a user, `edit` to edit a shout)
  - `userid` (`userid` of the moderator who executed the command in integer form)
  - `comment` (integer of the user's `userid` who is being banned)

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head you would want to use a subquery to search for the users who are actually banned and use those user_id's to get all your info out of the shoutbox-database.

```
 SELECT * FROM shoutbox WHERE comment IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE chat_banned = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query only shows ban activity on users who are still banned:

```
SELECT u.username, s.time, s.command, bu.username AS moderator
FROM shoutbox s 
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.userid = s.comment
INNER JOIN users bu
ON bu.userid = s.userid
WHERE u.chatbanned = 1
AND s.command = 'ban'
ORDER BY s.time DESC
```

Comment: What does this `bu.*` prefix stand for and mean?

Comment: The s, u, and bu are aliases for the tables that participate in the query. Aliases not only reduce typing, but they also serve to disambiguate which objects you mean when the query has to reference multiple columns or tables that have the same name. For example, this query includes a second join to the users table in order to resolve the moderator's username, so we need an alias to differentiate it from the other join.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm heading out for the USA Science & Engineering Fest so I won't have time to test this until tomorrow morning but from the looks of it, this seems like the answer I'm looking for. I'll report back what happens :)